# Maximum KML file size that Google Map Android API can load

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kml

Recently i had a project that load KML on Google Map Android API.
On small file KML (65KB), it can load properly use LocalResource.
Afterthat i changed that file to my main KML that size (~13MB).
I have tried create AsyncTask to do that task, but Android Ur app didn't response wait or close.
My guide to load KML file on Android was from [Google Map Android Util Library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

Does any body know how big KML file that can't be load in Android?

Comment: Have you check is there any kind of problem on content to your new KML file?

Comment: actually the main KML that i used was from KMZ file. That KMZ file i extracted.. [KMZ file (1mb)](https://dropfile.to/54VQ36F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [KML Support page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions)

```
Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)
3MB

Maximum uncompressed KML file size
10MB

Maximum number of network Links
10

Maximum number of total document-wide features
1,000
```

Without knowing more about your KML content, it seems to make sense that the limit would gate you after loading four